# Get Touch events from Viewpager within a fragment

Tags: android

I have `DialogFragment` inside which I have implemented `viewpager`.To use `onTouch` event of `viewpager` ; I have override  `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)` method but when i swipe pages `ACTION_DOWN` event does not fire.I am able to get `ACTION_UP` and `ACTION_MOVE` but not `ACTION_DOWN`.Please Help me.

My XML file is:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/xrellayDetailsParent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:splitMotionEvents="false" 
   >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/xvw"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/xvw"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0.1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/xlinlaySharebar"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/xlinlaySharebar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ximgvwFont"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/text" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ximgvwShare"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/share" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ximgvwFav"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/fav" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: could you show your java code plz?

Comment: In java code,I have just initialize viewpager by findviewbyId and attach a onTouchListener.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but in your xml code I saw :

> `<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>       xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>       android:id="@+id/xrellayDetailsParent"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="match_parent"
>       android:background="@drawable/app_bg"
>       android:clickable="true"
>       **android:splitMotionEvents="false"**`

In [Here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0.html) Google said that if your groupview has

> android:splitMotionEvents="false"

that means child views in the ViewGroup cannot split touch events—only one view can receive touch events at a time.

So I think you should try to change this value from `false`  --> `true`